# What makes a norm-Gaussian inner product space "infinite-dimensional"?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, functions, vector-spaces, inner-products

Suppose we define an $\mathbb{R}^m$ inner product space in which the inner product of $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ is $\exp\left(-\|\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y}\|\right)$. In PCA and machine learning, we say that there are infintely many dimensions in this inner product space.

Prove that there exists no finite-dimensional vector-valued function $\Phi$ such that $$\exp\left(-\|\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y}\|^2\right)\propto \Phi\left(\mathbf{x}\right) \left[\Phi\left(\mathbf{y}\right)\right]^\mathrm{T},$$

and suggest *somehow* that the above statement is valid in some infinite-dimensional space.

---

## Edit 0

Okay, so it's not an inner product space because it doesn't meet bilinearity. But can you still prove the above statement? That is, that the Gaussian formula is not an inner product in any finite-dimensioned $\Phi : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ (where $m$ can be large) space defined as $\Phi\left(\mathbf{x}\right)$ for each $\mathbf{x}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

---

## Edit 1

["infinite-dimensional" reference.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131007/integrating-length-for-input-space-feature-pc-projections-in-kernel-pca)

Comment: How can $\exp(-\Vert \mathbf x - \mathbf y \Vert)$ be an inner product according to any normal usage of the term?  If we set $\langle \mathbf x, \mathbf y \rangle = \exp(-\Vert \mathbf x - \mathbf y \Vert)$, how does bilinearity work?  Thanks.

Comment: @RobertLewis I believe that is is kind of an inner product in the transformed space.

Comment: Here's a sketch for a proof in my mind. Multiplying a vector and a column vector gives a linear combination of terms, which can be polynomial. The hypothetical vectors are infinite-dimensional because they multiply to a Taylor series converging on the kernel result.

Comment: I'll need some time to think about this.  .  .